# Datagrid in Create, Edit page

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to create a `Datagrid` inside `Create`, `Edit` page to display and manage `n-to-n` relationship. But I don't know how to pass `props` into `List` and `Datagrid` and what `props` should be passed.

The Resource to manage this Datagrid named `caregiver_student` and I put it in my custom `restClient` file.

Basic info
[image: Basic info]

Relationship info
[image: Relationship info]

Here is my code:

```
<Edit title={<CaregiverTitle />} {...props}>
    <TabbedForm>
        <FormTab label="Personal Info">
            <DisabledInput source="id" />
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="email" />
            <TextInput source="phone" />
            <RadioButtonGroupInput source="account_type" choices={[
                { id: 10, name: 'Caregiver' },
                { id: 20, name: 'Guardian' },
            ]} optionText="name" optionValue="id" />
            <BooleanInput source="status" label="Active"/>
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Relationship">
            <List actions={<RelationActions/>} location={false} title={" "}>
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextField source="name" label="Student"/>
                    <TextField source="relationship" />
                    <EditButton />
                    <DeleteButton />
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
        </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
</Edit>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked resources should be enclosed in a [ReferenceManyField](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencemanyfield)

You can find a complete example in the demo,
 especially the [Customers Edit component](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/visitors/index.js#L68)

Someone started a PR which might help: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/744

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there are more than thousand students that separated by hundred classes. It's really hard to select a student.

Comment: You mean you'd like a filter in the DataGrid ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar page with a tab that lists "Batchunits" that belong to a particular "batchid".

```
<FormTab label="resources.batches.tabs.batchunits">
    <ReferenceManyField addLabel={false} reference="Batchunits" target="batchid">
         <Datagrid bodyOptions={{ stripedRows: true, showRowHover: true}} >
           <TextField source="unitcode" />
           <DateField source="harvested" />
           <BooleanField source="contaminated" label="Contaminated"/>
           <TextField source="note" style={{ maxWidth: '10em', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }} />
           <EditUnitButton />
         </Datagrid>
    </ReferenceManyField>
</FormTab>
```

But in this setup, Formtab will not accept a Create "button" to create a record of another resource. e.g another "Batchunit. Would be very useful to create another linked Batchunit. Don't know how to do that...

Comment: This is not supported at the moment. Someone started a PR which might help: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/744